# Min value on main diagonal of the 2D Array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, diagonal

I managed to create a 2d array and populate it automatically with my code. I'd like to find the min value on the main diagonal, but I'm stuck and have no idea how to approach that idea from my code. Can anyone explain me how can I manage to achieve this pretty please? Everything that I've tried or come up with gave no results whatsoever..

```
var matrix = Array.from(Array(10), () => new Array(10));

for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    for(j=0; j<10; j++)
    matrix[i][j] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    
}


console.log(matrix);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct a 1-d array of the diagonal.  Use Math.min with .apply to find the min value in that array.

```js
var matrix = Array.from(Array(10), () => new Array(10));

for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    for(j=0; j<10; j++)
    matrix[i][j] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    
}
const diag = matrix.map((m, i) => m[i]);
const min = Math.min.apply(null, diag);
console.log(diag, "min = " + min);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked like a charm. Perfect solution for my problem!

Answer (score 1):

The main diagonal of 2D Square Array (Matrix) is always at `col_index == row_index`, so you can iterate through the array to find the minimum value through it.

I made the array to 3x3 in my snippet to show the simpler case, but you may get it to 10x10 to try as well.

```js
function getMinimumOfDiag(arr) {

 var min = Infinity;
 
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  if(arr[i].length > i)
    if(arr[i][i] < min)
      min = arr[i][i]

 return min;
};

var matrix = Array.from(Array(3), () => new Array(3));

for(i=0; i<3; i++){
  for(j=0; j<3; j++)
    matrix[i][j] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);    
}

console.log(matrix);
console.log(getMinimumOfDiag(matrix));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the matrix has rows and columns of same length, This should work,

```js
var matrix = Array.from(Array(10), () => new Array(10));
const matrixLength = 10;

for(let i=0; i<matrixLength; i++){
    for(j=0; j<matrixLength; j++)
    matrix[i][j] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    
}
let minValueInDiagonal = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
for(let i = 0; i < matrixLength; i++) {
  minValueInDiagonal = Math.min(matrix[i][i], minValueInDiagonal);
}

console.log("Matrix is", matrix);
console.log("Min value in diagonal is: ", minValueInDiagonal);
```